# Unrecognized element 'system.codedom' in appSettings as external file

Tags: .net, appsettings

After updating regular .NET app package: Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform to 4.1.0 it started to break appSettings file by injecting <system.codedom> into appSettings as external file. Web.config has  so app.config gets modified. Is there any fix for this? I can only think of making app.config file as not writable.

[image]